# Code Igniter Custom Field Validation Not Working

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I created a custom validation in Code Igniter. I have the following code  but the `is_FieldUnique` validation is not working. Even if, I `var_dump()` the parameters still I am not getting the it was displaying. What am I doing wrong with my code below? I am not getting any return with the `is_FieldUnique` but the default validation is working fine like the `required`, `min_length`.

In `application/libraries/Customfieldvalidation.php`, I have this line of code below:

```
class Customfieldvalidation extends CI_Form_validation 
    {
        public function is_FieldUnique($str, $field)
        {
            var_dump($str);
            var_dump($field);
            list($table, $field)=explode('.', $field);
            $q = $this->CI->db->query("SHOW KEYS FROM $table WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'")->row();
            $primary_key = $q->Column_name;
            if($this->CI->input->post($primary_key) > 0):
                $query = $this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str,$primary_key.' !='=>$this->CI->input->post($primary_key)));
            else:
                $query = $this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str));
            endif; 
            echo $query;
            exit();
            return $query->num_rows() === 0;
        }
    }
```

In my controller, I have this code:

```
class User extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('customfieldvalidation');
    }
    function _setRules()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'required|valid_email|min_length[8]|is_FieldUnique[users.email_address]');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('is_FieldUnique', '* must have a unique value');
    }
}
```

What could be the reason that the custom field is not working? I know this could be pretty simple for everyone but I'm new to Codeigniter and starting to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must correctly prefix your custom library if you are extending a native library. The default prefix is `MY_` this can be changed in `application/config/config.php`, with this config: `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';`.

So this:

```
class Customfieldvalidation extends CI_Form_validation
```

Should be:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
```

Also ensure that the file name reflects this and is in the appropriate location:

```
application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php
```

You'll also need a constructor to extend the parent class:

```
function __construct($rules = array())
{
    parent::__construct($rules);
}
```

Ensure that you're loading the library in your controller or [autoload](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html) it. You don't need to include the class prefix when you load the library:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

I'm guessing you've added a few of the lines in your `is_FieldUnique` function for debugging, but you definitely don't want `exit()` before the `return` as this will exit the script and won't allow anything to be returned. It's also not clear to me what the function is returning (maybe I'm just being dim!), so a statement like this should help:

```
if ($query->num_rows() === 0)
{
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

You could also consider using a [callback](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks), which is a common way of adding your own validation rules.

Comment: Yes, its for debugging purposes only. I added exit() to double check if the methods were executed. But sad to say in my code, none of my custom validation methods successfully executed. I will try your code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but the custom field validation is not working still. I debug the code step by step and I found out the issue. I got this error message, Unable to find validation rule: is_Fieldunique. I have load the custom library in my controller. What could be the problem here?

Comment: I've edited my answer to go into a bit more detail - hopefully that'll be useful to help you load and use your validation function. You also seem to be passing only 1 parameter to the validation function expecting 2.

Comment: Thank you, it takes me time to figure it out. In CI, you can't just use any class name or else it wont load. So I change my class name from "My_Customfieldvalidation" to "MY_Form_validation".