# CodeIgniter call a callback within a custom form_validation class

Tags: php, codeigniter

Basically I want to use a callback validation method **inside** an extended class of `Form_validation`.

**OK CASE**

I make `MY_Form_validation` class with the public callback method.

Loaded in my controller as:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation'); 
}
```

used in this controller as:

```
$this->form_validation->validate();
```

I use it like this inside the custom form class:

```
$this->CI->form_validation->set_rules('field', 'field', 'check_callback');
```

Note that it is not called as `callback_<name of method>` which is I do not know either why it *only* works without the `callback_` prefix *when* called inside its own class.

**NOK CASE**

I make `MY_Custom_form_validation` class with the public callback method.

Loaded in my controller as:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('my_custom_form_validation');
}

$this->my_custom_form_validation->validate();
```

**Same settings as OK CASE when used in `set_rules` but this time I get the following error**:

```
Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name field.(check_callback)
```

Why is this happening? They only differed in file name and way of loading! Did I miss something here?

Or there should only be ONE extended `MY_Form_validation` that will contain the entire validation for the entire project? Does CI really prevents this custom class *aside from* `MY_Form_validation`?

---

`MY_Form_validation.php`

```
<?php
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct($rules = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($rules);
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function validate()
    {
        $this->CI->form_validation->set_rules('value', 'value',
            'trim|required|integer|check_value['.$this->CI->input->post('unit').']');
        $this->CI->form_validation->set_rules('unit', 'unit', 'trim|required');
    }

    public function check_value($value, $unit)
    {
        if($value >= 100)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('check_value',
                'The %s must be greater than or equal 100.');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

`MY_Custom_form_validation.php`

```
<?php
class MY_Custom_form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct($rules = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($rules);
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function validate()
    {
        $this->CI->form_validation->set_rules('value', 'value',
            'trim|required|integer|check_value['.$this->CI->input->post('unit').']');
        $this->CI->form_validation->set_rules('unit', 'unit', 'trim|required');
    }

    public function check_value($value, $unit)
    {
        if($value >= 100)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('check_value',
                'The %s must be greater than or equal 100.');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

`Form.php`, please note of the **OK CASE** and **NOT OK**

```
<?php
class Form extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        // OK CASE
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        // NOK CASE
        $this->load->library('my_custom_form_validation');
        $this->load->model('prf_model');
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        $data['username'] = 'my_username';
        $data['title'] = 'Submit a PRF';
        $data['last_order_submission'] =
            ($this->prf_model->get_last_prf_order_submission()+1);

        // OK CASE
        $this->form_validation->validate();
        // NOK CASE
        $this->my_custom_form_validation->validate();

        if(!$this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/form', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_save_to_database($_POST);
            redirect('form/success');
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand you right, is it like you want to have 2 custom form validation?  First one is "MY_Form_validation " and second is "MY_Custom_form_validation " ?

Comment: No, I want to *not* have `MY_Form_validation` but have `MY_Custom_form_validation` instead because I plan to create many `MY_Form_name_form_validation` classes.

Comment: Show us the definition of MY_Custom_form_validation

Comment: @DFriend, there you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue before, in CI you cant just use any custom validation name it should be MY_Form_validation. Check this, [Code Igniter Custom Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002237/code-igniter-custom-field-validation-not-working)

Comment: I don't know the reason at all. I also had a hard time debugging that before.

Comment: Thank you for helping a brother out.

Comment: The reason why dates back to a time when there was little or no support for class autoloading in PHP. The "MY_" prefix when added to a core class name was a way to make sure the file for the parent (core) class (e.g. CI__Form_validation) could be found and instantiated before trying to instantiate the child class (e.g. `MY_Form_validation.php`) . If you are not trying to extend a core library class you do not need to use the `MY_` prefix.

Comment: If you implement an autoload function within CI you can easily `extend` any class you want - core or custom. Ways 2 & 3 in [this article](http://avenir.ro/codeigniter-tutorials/no-more-my_controller-how-you-can-create-more-than-one-base-controller/) are, IMO, the best ways to implement one for yourself. You can then get a definition like `Class Custom_form_validation extends MY_form_validation {...` to work the way you expect.